# How to use SET PATH instead of currentfunctionpath for calling SP in DB2

Tags: db2

Currently i have configured to user currentfuntionpath in connection string to call SP in Db2. How can i user SET PATH instead of "currentfunctionpath" ?

Comment: Is the question about how to use the [SET PATH statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-set-path)?

Comment: Yes Mark and also where can it be used. Can it be used in the config file or in the application code.

Comment: `SET PATH` is an executable statement, which you can run as any other statement with your application. There is a [CurrentFunctionPath IBM data server driver configuration keyword](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=keywords-currentfunctionpath), if you want to use a "config file" for your ODBC / CLI applications.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply. can we not use SET PATH in config file or in application code before making DB2 connection ? Currently i am already using currentfunctionpath in config file. Reason why i was looking to use SET PATH because with CurrentFunctionPath there are lot of thread calls goes to DB2 from application. And we thought with SET PATH we may reduce some.

Comment: I have no idea about your "config file", and how it's used. You should specify that explicitly. I don't understand your phrase "with CurrentFunctionPath there are lot of thread calls goes to DB2 from application", because I don't understand how `CurrentFunctionPath` would be related to the "lot of thread calls".